# Setting Odoo default value from XML data file not working

Tags: odoo

I'm trying to set the default value for the `type` field on the `product.product` model to `product`. I thought this would be simple using a data file. This is the content of my file:

```xml
<odoo>
    <function model="ir.values" name="set_default"
        eval="('product.product', 'type', 'product')"/>
</odoo>
```

The module imports without errors, but the default value is not created. It's nowhere to be found. Am I doing something wrong here?

I tried it this way as well, but same result:

```xml
<odoo>
    <function model="ir.values" name="set_default">
        <value>product.product</value>
        <value>type</value>
        <value>product</value>
    </function>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 0):

your syntax needs little correction

Try this and it will work :)

```
<function model="ir.values" name="set_default">
    <value eval="str('product.product')"/>
    <value eval="str('type')"/>
    <value eval="str('product')"/>
</function>
```

Because each value should be passed individual as per signature sequence.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean a bit more? How do you know it needs to be written that way? The two methods I tried I got from other examples in the code. What is it that determines which syntax is needed?

Comment: By the way, it didn't work. Same result. Module imports fine, but there is no default value in place.

Comment: As mentioned in odoo docs: 'function tag should evaluate to a sequence of parameters to call the method' and that is why i wrote it in sequence as they are in method signature. and it is working for v8.0

Comment: you can check this example of account mdoule > https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/addons/account/account_unit_test.xml#L51

Comment: I am using version `10.saas~14+e`, and it is not working.

Comment: hmm then only one thing could be wrong that you have "noupdate"  set in  <data> tag.!!!